# Can I just run one port to send packet continuously in Pktgen?

Tags: c, generator, dpdk

I want to accomplish to send packet continuously in port "0",and I have done some configuraition:

```
./app/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/pktgen -l 0-2 -n 4 --proc-type auto --socket-mem 1024 -b 00:08.0 -- -P -m "[1].0"
```

and in the interactive CLI I set something:

```
Pktgen>set 0 src ip "192.168.12.2/24"
Pktgen>set 0 dst ip "192.168.12.3"
Pktgen>set 0 proto udp
Pktgen>set 0 count 0
Pktgen>set 0 rate 50
Pktgen>set 0 size 64
Pktgen>start 0
```

But according to the `page main` display, the `port 0` just transmit few packets and stop to send packet anymore,even I `stop 0` and `start 0` again, there is no any response.

Pktgen must config two dpdk ports? when I config two dpdk ports and run `scripts/rfc2544_tput_test.lua`, it works well,I want to know why...

Comment: the DPDK version 17.11.3, the pktgen version 3.4.9

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. It work seamlessly. Only requirement, the other side should be able to detect link state change.

[image]

Comment: pktgen version: 3.4.9, dpdk version: Version: DPDK 17.11.3

Comment: thank you all the same,  I just have found the requirement you said :)

Comment: please feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it's has worked out for you